# create-react-app using third party component libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use third party components in my react app.

I have used `create-react-app` to create basic app.

Now i want to include UIKIT Components into with this react app. [UIKIT Components](http://otissv.github.io/react-uikit-components/docs.html#/base?_k=ysd3bh)

I have installed it as instructed but not displaying styles etc.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';

import uikit from 'react-uikit-base';
import Panel from 'react-uikit-panel';

const Component2 = (props) => {
const cssClassNames = uikit.helpers.cleanClasses([
  this.props.classes,
  this.props.className
]);

return <div className={cssClassNames}>
  {this.props.children}
</div>;
};

uikit.base(Component2);


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="App">
         <Panel title='Title' badge={{body: 'hot', context: 'danger'}}>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
           </Panel>


      </div>
    );
   }
 }

export default App;
```

**Here is what it's displaying:**

[image]